# Remix not letting workspace download

Tags: solidity, remix, explorers, ide

Remix doesn't allow me download the workspace. I've been trying to hit the download button, but it doesn't allow me download the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

So there might be some issue with the browser's cache. There are multiple solutions to it:

1. Change your Browser(Brave/Chrome),Either one of them if one's not working.
   (Dont try to clear cache that just removes your workspace)
2. You can go in incognito mode, But that just's empties out the works-space.